# Copy Azure SQL Users using Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, devops

I have two SQL databases, dev and test, which are hosted on Microsoft Azure. There is a release pipeline for copying a database from dev to test environment. I use `az db copy` command for the copy operation. The users are different in test and dev, so I need to copy all users from another DB on the test environment using the azure pipeline task.

What is the proper solution to copy the users from db 2 to db 1?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default task in azure pipeline to copy the users from db 2 to db 1. You could  try to use Azure PowerShell task to query each database and move data between them as needed. Here's an [example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4224/getting-started-querying-your-azure-sql-database-in-powershell/) on how to get this done.

```
Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer
$ipAddress = (Invoke-WebRequest 'http://myexternalip.com/raw').Content -replace "`n"
New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule -ServerName $serverName -RuleName 'ClientRule' -StartIpAddress $ipAddress -EndIpAddress $ipAddress
$params = @{
      'Database' = 'myazuredatabase'
      'ServerInstance' = 'yoursqinstance.database.windows.net'
      'Username' = 'adam'
      'Password' = 'mysecretpassword'
      'OutputSqlErrors' = $true
      'Query' = 'SELECT * FROM Users'
}
Invoke-Sqlcmd @params
```

Answer (score -2):

You can run add Users name SQL Script as Task in the pipeline after DB copy is complete.